# ¿Habilitar un botón con CheckBox en XAML y C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Estoy haciendo un formulario, pero me gustaría saber cómo hacer un `CheckBox`, `NAME=Permitir` que al pulsarlo habilitara un botón `NAME=Siguiente`, como los típicos *(Aceptar Términos y Condición)*.

Ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Que al no tocarlos este botón va a estar bloqueado y de lo contrario estará desbloqueado.

Comment: Deberias usar el evento que tenes en el checkbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero vas a la propiedad enabled del botón y la pones a false, esto lo haces a través del object inspector, de esta forma ya la aplicación se ejecuta con el botón deshabilitado posteriormente en el evento onClick del checkbox pones

```
miBoton.IsEnabled = miCheckBox.IsChecked.Value;
```

Este código habilita el botón cuando el checkbox está marcado y deshabilita el botón cuando se desmarca el checkbox

Comment: Me sale este error = Gravedad Código Descripción Proyecto Archivo LíneaEstado suprimido Error CS0079 El evento 'ToggleButton.Checked' solo puede aparecer a la izquierda de += o -=. Menu  C:\Users\compac\Desktop\Gran proyecto (No tocar)\Menu\Menu\MainWindow.xaml.cs 35 Activo

Comment: Ya se arregló, prueba lo nuevo que puse

Comment: gracias por tu ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Así:

```
<CheckBox x:Name="Permitir" Content="Acepto los Términos"/>
<Button x:Name="Siguiente" IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=Permitir, Path=IsChecked}" Content="Enviar"/>
```

Para que estés al tanto, puedes bindear (linkear) el estado del botón directo al estado del checkbox sin usar código, solo a través de XAML y esta es la manera.

Ojalá te sirva.

Answer (score 0):

Podrías intentar algo así, usando el patrón de diseño MVVM:

Creas una propiedad booleana dentro de tu ViewModel

```
public bool CheckTerms { get; set; }
```

Luego, bindeas la propiedad al botón en XAML

```
<Button IsEnable="{Binding CheckTerms }"/>
```